# Column Matching with Python and Snowflake

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a ton of data files some with different header names(ie First Name, FName, First-name) and/or column order (Column 2 is phone in one sheet and it's column 3 in another).

I'm trying to get all of these files into Snowflake so I can run analysis and have fun with the data.

Is there a Python Script that will read the file(s) and will allow me to match them up with the columns I have in Snowflake?

Comment: There are several scripts that could do that, but what is important is what have you done so far and where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: @Datanovice I haven't even started yet, except for trying to bulk upload the files into snowflake and realizing that the columns are all different in terms of naming conventions and order :(

Comment: I think you'll need to show some effort and research before asking for help on here - since SO is not a code writing service. What I would suggest, is reading in all the files with `nrows=1` in `pandas` and looking at the headers, you can then manually fix them and do a map like replacement before inserting them into your dB.

Comment: @Datanovice Thanks for the input! I'll check out {pandas}! Any suggestions on GUI related scripts? I'm definitely not looking for people to write code for me, but rather point me in the right direction. :)

Comment: What Datanovice said. Pandas is probably your best friend. You can read each file into a dataframe, re-order/re-name your columns and maybe even do some data clean up and then write each dataframe back to file. You can write the files back separately or append each dataframe to the same file

Comment: @KirkHolmes probably not the best place for such a discussion, come into the Python [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) happy to chat there.

Answer (score -1):

Snowflake is a cloud data warehouse platform where you can load data as a traditional data warehouse and write SQLs for data exploration. It also provides extension to load data and process them. However, unlike pandas and spark, it does not infer a schema for a developer.

If you really like to do this operation via snowflake, what is recommends is

1. Load your data to S3 bucket and then stage it (you need to understand the staging process) ([reference](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-stage.html))
2. You can also stage data from the local disk to a virtual warehouse.
3. Once data is there in the stage environment, create a virtual warehouse (VW) and then create a database/table as per the schema ([reference](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql-ddl-summary.html))
4. and now you can write queries to explore data
5. However, if you want to do exploratory work on data itself, you can simply use your local machine and then create a clean data set in snowflake for curation or further processing.

Hope this approach helps you to clarify how to use snowflake and not to confused with python or other data processing tools.